# Android-Phonegap-MySql synchronization

Tags: android, mysql, database, cordova, synchronization

I want to develop an Android-Phonegap app with a bidirectional synchronization to a mysql database(server-client and client-server).
Which is the best method for doing that, do you know some examples or good tutorials? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something of this sort myself. I used JSONP to send/receive data from my application to a PHP file hosted on my server. If there's a change in the in-app database, you can propagate it to the server using AJAX.

Now for the change in the database on the server, you could set a flag on the server side once there's a change and make your app periodically check if there's any update and sync your app using a JSON call. This might be the easy way, but if you are looking for realtime push notifications, you could consider taking a look at these:

1. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/android-push-notifications-with-phonegap.html
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464500/phonegap-push-notification-for-android